# A complex number inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

We have real numbers $p,q,r \gt 0$. 
 Then show that, for all complex numbers $z\neq 0$,  $$|z-p|+|z-q\omega|+|z-r\omega^{2}|\gt p+q+r$$ Here, $\omega=e^\frac{i2\pi}{3}$
Actually, I came to this equation to prove that the unique point in a triangle $ABC$(where all angles are less than $\frac {2\pi}{3}$) which subtends equal angles on the three sides , i.e. $\frac {2\pi}{3}$, is the Fermat point, which minimises the distance $PA+PB+PC$ for all points $P$ lying in the plane of $ABC$. So, I really do not intend to find a geometrical solution to this one. Please help!

Comment: Yes, @DonAntonio that's what I meant. Thanks for it. I'll input it in the question, to avoid confusion.

Comment: What makes you think that this is a good approach for a calculatory proof of the properties of the Fermat point?

Comment: Well, I don't know if it is one @Phira. It just came to my mind that it could be shown in this way, but I really don't know where to start.

Comment: stated this way, the result has great aesthetic value

Answer (score 0):

there is a rather boring partial answer, if I have not misunderstood (which, unfortunately is all too often the case).

let O be the point $(0,0)$ so that:
$$ A = (p,0) \\
B= (-\frac{q}2,\frac{\sqrt{3}}2q) \\
C=(-\frac{r}2,-\frac{\sqrt{3}}2r) 
$$
and set $P=(X,Y)$
then
$$s(X,Y)=PA + PB + PC= \\
\left((X-p)^2 +Y^2\right)^{\frac12}+\left((X+\frac{q}2)^2 +(Y-\frac{\sqrt{3}q}2)^2\right)^{\frac12}+\left((X+\frac{r}2)^2 +(Y+\frac{\sqrt{3}}2r)^2\right)^{\frac12}$$
it is simple, and only mildly tedious, to verify that:
$$\frac{\partial s}{ \partial x}|_{(0,0)} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial s}{ \partial y}|_{(0,0)} = 0
$$
and we have 
$$s(0,0) = p+q+r
$$

Comment: David, this is more suitable as a comment. Someone flagged your post as "low quality" and I must agree. The question states $z\neq 0$.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @IanMateus Ian, yes, agreed. I deleted the answer quickly, but that hasty gaffe served at least to keep the question in my mind, which I think is a very good one. sorry for any offense given by my foolishness. I hope the present partial answer is not another misunderstanding on my part. it appeared from the wording that OP did not want a geometric proof, though personally I would find that approach more aesthetically satisfying as well as more mathematically challenging.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately, I have already recommended deletion, but people will see your edit and won't delete it.